# Retrieve and assign gameId to multiple players in Cloud Function transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBvWaTTxfmo&ab_channel=uNicoDev) and trying to add a third player to the game. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/rotolonico/Unity-Firebase-Multiplayer-Example/blob/master/Assets/index.js) that works for two players. Below is my data structure:

```
  "matchmaking" : {
    "32idNK8OndcujN8CFNe3VBTxsXL2" : {
      "gameId" : "placeholder"
    },
    "LnMnOtdLJYbsRuTeUpeHfaAhpX32" : {
      "gameId" : "placeholder"
    },
    "plpISHWWtuNJvhSlFwfik6DOHR53" : {
      "gameId" : "placeholder"
    }
  }
```

I have a cloud function that is called every time a user joins the matchmaking room. Depending on whichever two users are available, the function generates a unique game room for all three users. I am not well-versed in Javascript so I've been struggling on this for a while.

**How can I retrieve and assign the gameId value to three players during a transaction?**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();

exports.matchmaker = functions.database.ref('matchmaking/{playerId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        var gameId = generateGameId();

        database.ref('matchmaking').once('value').then(snapshot => {
            var secondPlayer = null;
            var thirdPlayer = null;           
            
            // add two players into the queue 
            snapshot.forEach(child => { // check that its not the playerId who just joined  
                var playerId = child.key
                var gameId = child.val().gameId
                if (gameId === "placeholder" && playerId !== context.params.playerId) {
                    secondPlayer = child; 
                }             
            });         

            snapshot.forEach(child => { // check that its not the playerId who just joined 
                var playerId = child.key
                var gameId = child.val().gameId             
                if (gameId === "placeholder" && playerId !== secondPlayer.key && playerId !== context.params.playerId) {
                    thirdPlayer = child; 
                }                
            });            

            if (secondPlayer === null || thirdPlayer === null) return null; // one room needs three players                     
          
            database.ref("matchmaking").transaction(function (matchmaking) {

                console.log(matchmaking)                
                
                // ================================================ 
                // PROBLEM STARTS HERE
                // ================================================ 
                
                console.log("playerId gameId:",context.params.playerId.gameId)  // returns undefined                
                
                // If any of the players gets into another game during the transaction, abort the operation
                if (matchmaking === null || 
    context.params.playerId.gameId !== "placeholder" ||
    matchmaking[secondPlayer.key].gameId !== "placeholder" || 
    matchmaking[thirdPlayer.key].gameId !== "placeholder") return matchmaking; 


             //    matchmaking.forEach(player => { // check that its not the playerId that just joined  
                //  var playerId = player.key
                //  var gameId = player.val().gameId
                //     if (gameId !== "placeholder") {
                //      player["gameId"] = gameId;
                //     }             
                // });                    

                context.params.playerId.gameId = gameId; // assign game id to player 
                matchmaking[secondPlayer.key].gameId  = gameId; 
                matchmaking[thirdPlayer.key].gameId = gameId;
                return matchmaking;

            }).then(result => {

                if (result.snapshot.child(context.params.playerId).val() !== gameId) return;

                // ENDS HERE
                // ================================================ 

                var game = {
                    gameInfo: {
                        gameId: gameId,
                        playersIds: [context.params.playerId, secondPlayer.key, thirdPlayer.key]
                    },
                    turn: context.params.playerId
                }

                database.ref("games/" + gameId).set(game).then(snapshot => {

                    console.log("Game created successfully!")
                    return null;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

                return null;

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

            return null;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });

function generateGameId() {
    var possibleChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var gameId = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) gameId += possibleChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length));
    return gameId;
}
```

I've been getting errors such as `matchmaking.forEach is not a function` or `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` or `Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`

console.log(matchmaking) shows the following:

```
{ '32idNK8OndcujN8CFNe3VBTxsXL2': { gameId: 'placeholder' },
  LnMnOtdLJYbsRuTeUpeHfaAhpX32: { gameId: 'placeholder' },
  plpISHWWtuNJvhSlFwfik6DOHR53: { gameId: 'placeholder' } }
```

I would really appreciate any help.

**Update:**

Solution:

```
            database.ref("matchmaking").transaction(function (matchmakingSnapshot) {

                if (matchmakingSnapshot) {                      
                    matchmakingSnapshot[context.params.playerId].gameId = gameId; // assign game id to player 
                    matchmakingSnapshot[secondPlayer.key].gameId  = gameId; 
                    matchmakingSnapshot[thirdPlayer.key].gameId = gameId;
                    return matchmakingSnapshot;     
                } else if ( // If any of the players gets into another game during the transaction, abort the operation
                    matchmakingSnapshot === null || 
                    context.params.playerId.gameId !== "placeholder" ||
                    matchmakingSnapshot[secondPlayer.key].gameId !== "placeholder" || 
                    matchmakingSnapshot[thirdPlayer.key].gameId !== "placeholder") {
                    return matchmakingSnapshot;    
                }                   

            }).then(result => {
```

The problem was that when I was trying to update the gameId, the transaction returns a null data. I had to make sure matchmaingSnapshot is not null before accessing the context params playerId. I'm not sure why calling matchmakingSnapshot.val() returns function undefined, but yeah that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You should not currently be getting the error `matchmaking.forEach is not a function`.

The ".forEach" function can work on an array *or* on a DataSnapshot (where it iterates over the children, providing a DataSnapshot of each in turn).

But if you have an Object, ".forEach" will give you the error message you describe. The code as it stands appears to be having "matchmaking" as a DataSnapshot, so it should be ok for ".forEach" at the moment.

#### Explanation for error: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

I think you have accidentally inserted a variable name, instead of telling javascript to use the variable name's value

```
if (matchmaking === null || 
    matchmaking.context.params.playerId.gameId !== "placeholder" ||
    matchmaking.secondPlayer.key.gameId !== "placeholder" || 
    matchmaking.thirdPlayer.key.gameId !== "placeholder"
) return matchmaking;
```

I think you don't mean `matchmaking.secondPlayer.key.gameId`. I think you mean `matchmaking[secondPlayer].key.gameId`, so that if `secondPlayer` is "ABC123", you would be referring to `matchmaking.ABC123.key.gameId`

Same for thirdPlayer.

#### Explanation for error: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Did you mean just `context.params.playerId.gameId`, not `matchmaking.context.params.playerId.gameId`? You might have added the "matchmaking" by mistake?

#### Exploring the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'gameId' of undefined

If you get the above error with this:

```
matchmaking[context.params.playerId].key.gameId`
```

First, check that you need the step ".key". Looking at your object, it looks to me that ".gameId" comes straight after the matchmaking[playerId], with no ".key" needed. If you are sure you need the ".key", then I would debug as follows. Immediately before that statement, insert the following console logs.

```
console.log("playerId:",context.params.playerId)
console.log("matchmaking[context.params.playerId]:", 
    matchmaking[context.params.playerId])
```

Then check that the playerId is something sensible. If it isn't, console.log the entire context with

```
console.log("context:",JSON.stringify(context)) // This avoids getting something useless logged like `[Object object]`.
```

If the playerId is correct, you will then see if `matchmaking` has an entry for that player. This approach to debugging will eventually expose where the problem lies.

#### I think the final problem is the confusion between 'matchmaking' being a DataSnapshot versus a straightforward, writeable Object

This was hard for me to understand because matchmaking is currently a DataSnapshot, which is a somewhat confusing type of thing. It seems to get console.logged as though it is an object, but it isn't writeable.

I suggest we extract an actual object, as follows:

```
database.ref("matchmaking").transaction(function (matchmaking) {
    let matchmakingObject = matchmaking.val();

    // ... remainder of code as before, and then:

    matchmakingObject[context.params.playerId.gameId] = gameId; // assign game id to player 
    matchmakingObject[secondPlayer.key].gameId  = gameId; 
    matchmakingObject[thirdPlayer.key].gameId = gameId;
    return matchmakingObject;
```

I hope this fixes things!

My way to avoid such problems is to ALWAYS call snapshots xxxxSnapshot. That way I never forget that while it may console.log as though it was an object, in reality it is some sort of mystery thing.

For example, if I was writing this code, I would call things as follows:

```
database.ref("matchmaking")
.transaction(function (matchmakingSnapshot) {
    let matchmakingObject = matchmakingSnapshot.val();

    // ... remainder of code as before, and then:

    matchmakingObject[context.params.playerId.gameId] = gameId; // assign game id to player 
    matchmakingObject[secondPlayer.key].gameId  = gameId; 
    matchmakingObject[thirdPlayer.key].gameId = gameId;
    return matchmakingObject;
```

It's a bit ugly but less painful than trying to debug a name that has two powerfully different meanings that are easily conflated.

Comment: let me try doing matchmaking.val()

Comment: Yes! I want to retrieve the gameId  from the matchmaking object and then assign the newly generated gameId to each user

Comment: So I think you should change    matchmaking.secondplayer.key to matchmaking[secondPlayer].key

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'gameId' of undefined` when I try ` matchmaking[context.params.playerId].key.gameId`

Comment: So after debugging it shows the following `playerId: plpISHWWtuNJvhSlFwfik6DOHR53 ` for context.params.playerId and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'plpISHWWtuNJvhSlFwfik6DOHR53' of null` for matchmaking[context.params.playerId] but how can I get the gameId from the player id??

Comment: Excellent! This tells us that "matchmaking" is null. Can you update the question with your current version of the code, and indicate which line is generating this error message? I am no longer clear what code is current. I think we are nearly there. I don't think "matchmaking" can really be null. It is possible that it is a DataSnapshot, which might not be writeable. The problem you are facing may be through misinterpreting it as though it was merely an object. I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi Eureka, if above is not possible, would it be easier to structure my data [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488785/swift-firebase-snapshot-retrieve-single-value)?

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler. But it wouldn't fix the fundamental problem, that matchmaking is not an object, but a snapshot. 

Have you tried the final element in my answer? I think that is the key. Avoiding mixing up Object and DataSnapshot data types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223538/discussion-between-joan-and-eureka).